# php file/folder treeview for os disk and network paths

Tags: php, filetree

I am trying to make Intranet application in CentOS/Linux which lets users browse and select file placed anywhere on server or networks paths.

I just need to select file so I can get its full path where it is placed.
User must be able to browse folders as one would by

```
file --> open --> browse ...
```

paths could be ..

```
/home/username/
/datadrive/  --> mapped drive etc.
```

My current choice is Encode Explorer [enter link description here](http://encode-explorer.siineiolekala.net/?lang=en)

But I want it to work outside `/var/www/html` folder. What are my options ?

Answer (score 0):

In Encode Explorer index.php, edit line 350 according with your desired base dir.

Be aware that working outside of the www-folder may require you to remove the open_basedir restrictions introduced probably by your php.ini or an .htaccess.